# Black Opaque UIToolbar and UISearchBar look too much different

Tags: iphone, ios4, uisearchbar, uitoolbar

I need to show different "titlebar" for application, depending on situation. The problem with iOS4 is that **black opaque UIToolbar looks so much different that black opaque UISearchBar**. Have I messed up some settings or is there some work-arounds to make UIToolbar and UISearchBar use more similar coloring?

[image]

These are overlapping in real application, just wanted to show both at the same time. Usually UISearchBar covers left half of UIToolbar, so that only UISegmentedControl is visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records, this is the solution I used:

> How to Control UISearchBar Background Color
>   http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-control-uisearchbar-background.html

It's a bit fragile code, but worked just fine in one released application.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the barStyle to UIBarStyleDefault and changing the `tintColor` property on both; though it doesn't look like a color issue from the picture.  iOS3 introduced a UIBarStyleBlack along with the UIBarStyleOpaque - might look to see if that is being set anywhere in code instead of IB.